# mysql search number in table

Tags: mysql

i am using php/mysql.

i have a product table .
in which most product have starting name with number.

i want to listout all products start with any number.

any one have idea about it....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ref [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE name REGEXP '^[0-9]'
```

Answer (score -1):

from what i understant, your product names are something like '123myproduct'.
you should be able to search the table with

```
select * from product where name like '123%';
```

The *LIKE* construct uses '%' as a wildcard that means 'anything'

I hope this will help you

Jerome Wagner

Comment: from question  "start with any number" it is clearhe want result which start with any number.your query fails if it start with any other than '123'