# Check if string contains at least one digit

Tags: regex

I have got a text string like this:

```
test1test
```

I want to check if it contains at least one digit using a regex.

What would this regex look like?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned the simplest version:

```
\d
```

This will match any digit. If your regular expression engine is Unicode-aware, this means it will match anything that's defined as a digit in any language, not just the Arabic numerals 0-9.

There's no need to put it in `[`square brackets`]` to define it as a character class, as one of the other answers did; `\d` works fine by itself.

Since it's not anchored with `^` or `$`, it will match any subset of the string, so if the string contains at least one digit, this will match.

And there's no need for the added complexity of `+`, since the goal is just to determine whether there's *at least one* digit. If there's at least one digit, this will match; and it will do so with a minimum of overhead.

Comment: Java's string.matches("\\d") returns false, where string="test1test". Suggestions? See here http://fiddle.re/vf9w6

Comment: @Watt, if you play with that fiddle, you'll see that some methods *do* recognize the match -- `replaceFirst()` removes it, for example. It looks like [`matches` tries to match the entire string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4450166/87399), implicitly adding `^` at the beginning of the pattern and `$` at the end.

Answer (score 29):

The regular expression you are looking for is simply this:

```
[0-9]
```

You do not mention what language you are using. If your regular expression evaluator forces REs to be anchored, you need this:

```
.*[0-9].*
```

Some RE engines (modern ones!) also allow you to write the first as `\d` (mnemonically: ***d***igit) and the second would then become `.*\d.*`.

Answer (score 21):

In Java:

```
public boolean containsNumber(String string)
{
    return string.matches(".*\\d+.*");
}
```

Answer (score 17):

you could use look-ahead assertion for this:

```
^(?=.*\d).+$
```

Comment: Good grief, why make it that complicated?

Comment: @Joe: because most likely it's not the only check OP needs to do

Comment: This was helpful to require "at least one digit" and then to set a length range - the look-ahead ensures that no characters are consumed before the length check.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, in case you're looking for **all the words in a given string, which contain a number**

#### Pattern

```
\w*\d{1,}\w*
```

- `\w*` - Matches 0 or more instances of [A-Za-z0-9_]
- `\d{1,}` - Matches 1 or more instances of a number
- `\w*` - Matches 0 or more instances of [A-Za-z0-9_]

The whole point in `\w*` is to allow **not** having a character in the beginning or at the end of a word. This enables capturing the **first** and **last** words in the text.

If the goal here is to only get the numbers without the words, you can omit both `\w*`.

#### Given the string

```sh
Hello world 1 4m very happy to be here, my name is W1lly W0nk4
```

#### Matches

```sh
1 4m W1lly W0nk4
```

Check this example in regexr - https://regexr.com/5ff7q

Comment: P.s- the expression `{1,}` can be replaced with `+` as it has the same effect. Though for beginners, I think that the former is easier to read

Answer (score 1):

Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012286/mysql-search-number-in-table/3012305#3012305)

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE name REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

Comment: Fails for the string "bla1bla"

Comment: check again? '^[0-9]'  should be '[0-9]'

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
\d+
```

should work

Edit, no clue why I added the "+", without it works just as fine.

```
\d
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl:

```
if($testString =~ /\d/) 
{
    print "This string contains at least one digit"
}
```

where `\d` matches to a digit.

Comment: That's over-complex. `\d` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody falls here from google, this is how to check if string contains at least one digit in C#:

*With Regex*

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(myString, @"\d"))
{
  // do something
}
```

*Info: necessary to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions`*

*With linq:*

```
if (myString.Any(c => Char.IsDigit(c)))
{
  // do something
}
```

*Info: necessary to add `using System.Linq`*