# Difference between matches() and find() in Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to understand the difference between [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) and [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29).

According to the Javadoc, (from what I understand), `matches()` will search the entire string even if it finds what it is looking for, and `find()` will stop when it finds what it is looking for.

If that assumption is correct, I cannot see whenever you would want to use `matches()` instead of `find()`, unless you want to count the number of matches it finds.

In my opinion the String class should then have `find()` instead of `matches()` as an inbuilt method.

So to summarize:

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. When is it useful to use `matches()` instead of `find()`?

Comment: Be aware that calling `find()` multiple times may return different results for the same `Matcher`. See my answer below.

Comment: This question is about `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).matches()` and `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).find()`.

Answer (score 362, accepted):

`matches` tries to match the expression against the entire string and implicitly add a `^` at the start and `$` at the end of your pattern, meaning it will not look for a substring. Hence the output of this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("a123b");
    System.out.println(m.find());
    System.out.println(m.matches());

    p = Pattern.compile("^\\d\\d\\d$");
    m = p.matcher("123");
    System.out.println(m.find());
    System.out.println(m.matches());
}

/* output:
true
false
true
true
*/
```

`123` is a substring of `a123b` so the `find()` method outputs true. `matches()` only 'sees' `a123b` which is not the same as `123` and thus outputs false.

Comment: This answer is misleading. `matchers()` is not simply a `find()` with implied surrounding ^ and $. Be aware that calling `.find()` more than once may have different results if not preceeded by `reset()`, while `matches()` will always return same result. See my answer below.

Answer (score 106):

`matches` returns true if the whole string matches the given pattern. `find` tries to find a substring that matches the pattern.

Comment: You could say that `matches(p)` is the same as `find("^" + p + "$")` if that's any clearer.

Comment: Just an example to clarify the answer: "[a-z]+" with string "123abc123" will fail using matches() but will succeed using find().

Comment: @Max Exactly, `"123abc123".matches("[a-z]+")` will fail just as `"123abc123".find("^[a-z]+$")` would. My point was, that `matches()` goes for a complete match, just as `find()` with both start and end anchors.

Comment: `Pattern.compile("some pattern").matcher(str).matches()` is equal to `Pattern.compile("^some pattern$").matcher(str).find()`

Comment: @AlexR What I was trying to say (using a highly abbreviated syntax) :)

Comment: @jensgram, @AlexR: almost, but not exactly: `^` and `$` can be used to refer to the start and end of a line instead of the start and line of the complete input (in case of multi-line) input when [multiline mode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) is activated.

Comment: @AlexR / @jensgram: `...("some pattern").matcher(str).matches()` is *not* exactly equal to `...("^some pattern$").matcher(str).find()` that's only true in the first call. See my answer below.

Answer (score 86):

- `matches()` - will only return *true* if the **full string** is matched
- `find()` - will try to find **the next** occurrence within the
  substring that matches the regex.

Note the emphasis on "**the next**" in case of `find()`. That means, the result of calling `find()` multiple times might not be the same. In addition, by using `find()` you can call `start()` to return the position the substring was matched.

---

### Example

```
final Matcher subMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("skrf35kesruytfkwu4ty7sdfs");
System.out.println("Found: " + subMatcher.matches());
System.out.println("Found: " + subMatcher.find() + " - position " + subMatcher.start());
System.out.println("Found: " + subMatcher.find() + " - position " + subMatcher.start());
System.out.println("Found: " + subMatcher.find() + " - position " + subMatcher.start());
System.out.println("Found: " + subMatcher.find());
System.out.println("Found: " + subMatcher.find());
System.out.println("Matched: " + subMatcher.matches());

System.out.println("-----------");
final Matcher fullMatcher = Pattern.compile("^\\w+$").matcher("skrf35kesruytfkwu4ty7sdfs");
System.out.println("Found: " + fullMatcher.find() + " - position " + fullMatcher.start());
System.out.println("Found: " + fullMatcher.find());
System.out.println("Found: " + fullMatcher.find());
System.out.println("Matched: " + fullMatcher.matches());
System.out.println("Matched: " + fullMatcher.matches());
System.out.println("Matched: " + fullMatcher.matches());
System.out.println("Matched: " + fullMatcher.matches());
```

### Output

```
Found: false
Found: true - position 4
Found: true - position 17
Found: true - position 20
Found: false
Found: false
Matched: false
-----------
Found: true - position 0
Found: false
Found: false
Matched: true
Matched: true
Matched: true
Matched: true
```

---

So, be careful when calling `find()` multiple times if the `Matcher` object was not reset, even when the regex is surrounded with `^` and `$` to match the full string.

Comment: very helpful mate

Answer (score 7):

`find()` will consider the sub-string against the regular expression where as `matches()` will consider complete expression.

`find()` will returns true only if the sub-string of the expression matches the pattern.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");
        String candidate = "Java123";
        Matcher m = p.matcher(candidate);

        if (m != null){
            System.out.println(m.find());//true
            System.out.println(m.matches());//false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`matches();` does not buffer, but `find()` buffers. `find()` searches to the end of the string first, indexes the result, and return the boolean value and corresponding index.

That is why when you have a code like

```
1:Pattern.compile("[a-z]");

2:Pattern.matcher("0a1b1c3d4");

3:int count = 0;

4:while(matcher.find()){

5:count++: }
```

At **4:** The regex engine using the pattern structure will read through the whole of your code (index to index as specified by the `regex[single character]` to find at least one match. If such match is found, it will be indexed then the loop will execute based on the indexed result else if it didn't do ahead calculation like which `matches()`; does not. The while statement would never execute since the first character of the matched string is not an alphabet.