# Can't advance past endIndex Swift

Tags: swift, string, char

Something wrong with String Index when checking and deleting symbols. How can I improve it?

```
func romanToInt(_ s: String) -> Int {
    let romanDigits = ["I" : 1,
                       "V" : 5,
                       "X" : 10,
                       "L" : 50,
                       "C" : 100,
                       "D" : 500,
                       "M" : 1000]
    let romanSums = ["IV" : 4,
                     "IX" : 9,
                     "XL" : 40,
                     "XC" : 90,
                     "CD" : 400,
                     "CM" : 900]
    var sum = 0
    var str = s
    var charIndex = str.startIndex
    for index in str.indices {
        if index != str.index(before: str.endIndex) {
            charIndex = str.index(after: index)
        } else {
            charIndex = str.index(before: str.endIndex)
        }
        let chars = String(str[index]) + String(str[charIndex])
        if romanSums[chars] != nil {
            print(chars)
            str.remove(at: charIndex)
            sum += romanSums[chars]!
            print(sum)
        } else {
            let char = String(str[index])
            print(char)
            sum += romanDigits[char]!
            print(sum)
        }
        print(str)
    }

    return sum
}

let check = romanToInt("MCMXCIV")
```

**CONSOLE LOG:**

> ```
> M
> 1000
> MCMXCIV
> CM
> 1900
> MCXCIV
> XC
> 1990
> MCXIV
> IV
> 1994
> MCXI
> Fatal error: Can't advance past endIndex
> ```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949453/how-to-take-a-roman-numeral-string-and-convert-it-to-base10-digit/36949832?r=SearchResults&s=1|45.5005#36949832

Comment: @LeoDabus Your solution the fastest on LeetCode (32ms by removing the `guard` and `uppercased()` for speed) https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying the string you are iterating over, so your indices become invalid.  Instead, you could add a `skipChar` boolean that says that you've already handled the next character and then skip that character by executing `continue`:

```
func romanToInt(_ s: String) -> Int {
    let romanDigits = ["I" : 1,
                       "V" : 5,
                       "X" : 10,
                       "L" : 50,
                       "C" : 100,
                       "D" : 500,
                       "M" : 1000]
    let romanSums = ["IV" : 4,
                     "IX" : 9,
                     "XL" : 40,
                     "XC" : 90,
                     "CD" : 400,
                     "CM" : 900]
    var sum = 0
    var str = s
    var charIndex = str.startIndex
    var skipChar = false

    for index in str.indices {
        if skipChar {
            skipChar = false
            continue
        }
        if index != str.index(before: str.endIndex) {
            charIndex = str.index(after: index)
        } else {
            charIndex = str.index(before: str.endIndex)
        }
        let chars = String(str[index]) + String(str[charIndex])
        if romanSums[chars] != nil {
            print(chars)
            skipChar = true
            sum += romanSums[chars]!
            print(sum)
        } else {
            let char = String(str[index])
            print(char)
            sum += romanDigits[char]!
            print(sum)
        }
        print(str)
    }

    return sum
}

let check = romanToInt("MCMXCIV")
print(check)
```

> > ```
> > 1994
> > ```

Answer (score 2):

```
for index in str.indices {
    ...
        str.remove(at: charIndex)
```

It is not valid to modify a string while you are iterating over it. `str.indices` is fetched one time here, and is no longer valid once you've modified the underlying string.

I'm sure there will be a lot of implementations of this because it's the kind of small, fun problem that attracts implementations. So why not? This just screams recursion to me.

```
let romanDigits: [Substring: Int] = ["I" : 1,
                                     "V" : 5,
                                     "X" : 10,
                                     "L" : 50,
                                     "C" : 100,
                                     "D" : 500,
                                     "M" : 1000]
let romanSums: [Substring: Int] = ["IV" : 4,
                                   "IX" : 9,
                                   "XL" : 40,
                                   "XC" : 90,
                                   "CD" : 400,
                                   "CM" : 900]

func romanToInt<S: StringProtocol>(_ s: S) -> Int
    where S.SubSequence == Substring {

    if s.isEmpty { return 0 }

    if let value = romanSums[s.prefix(2)] {
        return value + romanToInt(s.dropFirst(2))
    } else if let value = romanDigits[s.prefix(1)] {
        return value + romanToInt(s.dropFirst(1))
    } else {
        fatalError("Invalid string")
    }
}

let check = romanToInt("MCMXCIV")
```

Of course this doesn't really check for valid sequences, so it's kind of junk. "IIIIXXIII" is kind of gibberish, but it works. But it's in keeping with the original approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` to make it flow here:

```
 func romanToInt(_ s: String) -> Int {
if s.isEmpty {return 0}

let romanDigits = ["I" : 1,
                   "V" : 5,
                   "X" : 10,
                   "L" : 50,
                   "C" : 100,
                   "D" : 500,
                   "M" : 1000]

let romanSums = ["IV" : 4,
                 "IX" : 9,
                 "XL" : 40,
                 "XC" : 90,
                 "CD" : 400,
                 "CM" : 900]
    return s.dropFirst().reduce((s.first!, romanDigits["\(s.first!)"]!)){

         return   ( $1,   //current char

                    $0.1 +   //previous sum

      (romanSums["\($0.0)\($1)"]     //add double value

     ?? ((romanDigits["\($1)"]!). +  romanDigits["\($0.0)"]!))  //or single value  and add duplicated

        -  romanDigits["\($0.0)"]!) // minus duplicated

     }.1

   }

   print(romanToInt("MCMXCIV")). //1994
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating `str` inside the loop, its end index is going change, in this case it gets lower than its original value. You can fix your code by checking that you haven't exceeded the `endIndex` on each iteration by using a while loop :

```
var index = str.startIndex
while index < str.endIndex {
    ...
    //Before the closing curly brace of the while loop
    index = str.index(after: index)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to reproduce a crash reported by one my users with the same message `Can't advance past endIndex` but I was not able to do it. Your code helped me figure out that this error changed in later versions of swift.

Your same code would report `cannot increment beyond endIndex` with swift 4.x runtime libraries, and `String index is out of bounds` with 5.x. The exact version numbers for the changes I do not know. But I suspect it is 4.0.0 and 5.0.0.-