# Sorting Royal Names using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort royal names. First Preference to the alphabet. If both names are same then I would like to sort by the roman numeral.
For Example if input is : King III, King II, Queen IX. (as 1st 2 strings are same they need to be sorted by their appended roman numeral)
So Expected output : King II, King III, Queen IX.

I tried storing roman numerals in a hashmap and writing a function that replaces roman numerals in given array to King 2, King 3, Queen 9 and then tried sorting but was not able to implement correctly.
Could anyone kindly help me with this?

Comment: did you research anything or did you already try anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
function romanToNum(roman) {
  if (roman === "")           return 0;
  if (roman.startsWith("L"))  return 50 + romanToNum(roman.substr(1));
  if (roman.startsWith("XL")) return 40 + romanToNum(roman.substr(2));
  if (roman.startsWith("X"))  return 10 + romanToNum(roman.substr(1));
  if (roman.startsWith("IX")) return 9  + romanToNum(roman.substr(2));
  if (roman.startsWith("V"))  return 5  + romanToNum(roman.substr(1));
  if (roman.startsWith("IV")) return 4  + romanToNum(roman.substr(2));
  if (roman.startsWith("I"))  return 1  + romanToNum(roman.substr(1));
  return 0;
}
console.log(
    ["King III", "King II", "Queen IX"]
      .map((n) => ({name: n, num: romanToNum(n.split(" ").pop())}))
      .sort((a, b) => (a.num - b.num))
      .map(({name, num}) => name)
  );
```

`romanToNum` function adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073150/converting-roman-numerals-to-decimal). The array is first mapped into `{name, num}` objects, then sorted on `num`, then converted back to `name`s only.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string and use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map), while comparing each element of the one with each element of the other one. if both elements are numbers, take the difference, otherwise return the result of `localeCompare`.

```js
function customSort(data, order) {

    function isNumber(v) {
        return (+v).toString() === v;
    }

    function isRoman(s) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/267405/1447675
        return /^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$/i.test(s);
    }

    function parseRoman(s) {
        var val = { M: 1000, D: 500, C: 100, L: 50, X: 10, V: 5, I: 1 };
        return s.toUpperCase().split('').reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
            return val[a] < val[aa[i + 1]] ? r - val[a] : r + val[a];
        }, 0);
    }

    var sort = {
            asc: function (a, b) {
                var i = 0,
                    l = Math.min(a.value.length, b.value.length);

                while (i < l && a.value[i] === b.value[i]) {
                    i++;
                }
                if (i === l) {
                    return a.value.length - b.value.length;
                }
                if (isNumber(a.value[i]) && isNumber(b.value[i])) {
                    return a.value[i] - b.value[i];
                }
                if (isRoman(a.value[i]) && isRoman(b.value[i])) {
                    return parseRoman(a.value[i]) - parseRoman(b.value[i]);
                }
                return a.value[i].localeCompare(b.value[i]);
            },
            desc: function (a, b) {
                return sort.asc(b, a);
            }
        },
        mapped = data.map(function (el, i) {
            var string = el.replace(/\d(?=[a-z])|[a-z](?=\.)/gi, '$&. .'),
                regex = /(\d+)|([^0-9.]+)/g,
                m,
                parts = [];

            while ((m = regex.exec(string)) !== null) {
                parts.push(m[0]);
            }
            return { index: i, value: parts, o: el, string: string };
        });

    mapped.sort(sort[order] || sort.asc);
    return mapped.map(function (el) {
        return data[el.index];
    });
}

var arr = ['King III', 'King II', 'Queen IX'];

console.log('sorted array asc', customSort(arr));
console.log('sorted array desc', customSort(arr, 'desc'));
console.log('original array', arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use your own convert table to get the decimal value of the roman numbers,
than a simple sort with the proper callback

```
var romanNumberToDec = {
  "I" : 1, "II" : 2, "III" : 3, "IV" : 4, "V" : 5,
  "VI" : 6, "VII" : 7, "VIII" : 8, "IX" : 9, "X" : 10
}
```

[ES6console](https://es6console.com/jd7sknha/) with the table

if thats all you need to deal with

but if you need a more generic way - [from selftaughtjs](https://www.selftaughtjs.com/algorithm-sundays-converting-roman-numerals/) -

```
function fromRoman(str) {  
   var result = 0;
   // the result is now a number, not a string
   var decimal = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];
   var roman = ["M", "CM","D","CD","C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X","IX","V","IV","I"];
   for (var i = 0;i<=decimal.length;i++) {
       while (str.indexOf(roman[i]) === 0){
         result += decimal[i];
         str = str.replace(roman[i],'');
       }
   }
   return result;
}


var arrayObj = [ "King III", "King II", "Queen IX"];

function mySort() {
    arrayObj.sort( (a, b)=> {
      let aNum = a.substr(a.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1, a.length);
      let bNum = b.substr(b.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1, b.length);
      // return romanNumberToDec[aNum] - romanNumberToDec[bNum]; 
      return fromRoman(aNum) - fromRoman(bNum);
    });
    console.log(arrayObj);
};

mySort();
```

[ES6console](https://es6console.com/jd7t5doc/) the generic way