# extract string from http document with matcher/pattern

Tags: java, android, regex

Here is a part of my document:

```
<td align="right" valign="top"><b>Име:</b></td> <td align="left" valign="top">Павлин Евгениев Тишев</td>
<td rowspan="7" align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right" valign="top"><b>Състояние:</b></td>
<td align="left" valign="top">Редовен</td>
```

I want to extract the String between `<td align="left" valign="top">` and `</td>` from all occurrences one by one because the values are ordered by type.

I am using this code (**in** is the whole input String part of which is shown above)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">(.*?)</td>");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

        if (m.matches()) {
            student.setName(m.group(1));
            student.setState(m.group(2));
        }
```

but it does not even enter the **if**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

```
while (m.find()) {
            student.setName(m.group(1));
            student.setState(m.group(2));
        }
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex) for understanding exactly why should you use `find()` and not `matches()`.