# Set minimum and maximum characters in a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I've written a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that matches any number of letters with any number of single spaces between the letters. I would like that regular expression to also enforce a minimum and maximum number of characters, but I'm not sure how to do that (or if it's possible).

My regular expression is:

```
[A-Za-z](\s?[A-Za-z])+
```

I realized it was only matching two sets of letters surrounding a single space, so I modified it slightly to fix that. The original question is still the same though.

Is there a way to enforce a minimum of three characters and a maximum of 30?

Comment: Any number of letters w/ any number of single spaces, with min 3 and max 30 characters? It sounds like `[A-Za-z ]{3,30}` will do the job, since it fits description.

Comment: @nhahtdh That would allow multiple spaces in the row. It seems there is no graceful solution.

Comment: It is possible, if you state **all** the requirements. I can only see your requirement of multiple spaces in a row from your regex, not from your description.

Comment: "with any number of single spaces between the letters." That was meant to mean there can be any number of spaces, so long as they are "single spaces," i.e. not more than one space in a row. I tried to be explicit about that requirement, but I guess it was difficult to describe.

Comment: This looks like a canonical question, but it is fairly late (2013), 5 years in.

Comment: A more general "question" is *[Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618)*. It has *"Min/max ranges (all inclusive)"*.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes

Just like `+` means one or more you can use `{3,30}` to match between 3 and 30

For example `[a-z]{3,30}` matches between 3 and 30 lowercase alphabet letters

From the [documentation of the Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> ```
> X{n,m}    X, at least n but not more than m times
> ```

In your case, matching 3-30 letters followed by spaces could be accomplished with:

```
([a-zA-Z]\s){3,30}
```

If you require trailing whitespace, if you don't you can use: (2-29 times letter+space, then letter)

```
([a-zA-Z]\s){2,29}[a-zA-Z]
```

If you'd like whitespaces to count as characters you need to divide that number by 2 to get

```
([a-zA-Z]\s){1,14}[a-zA-Z]
```

You can add `\s?` to that last one if the trailing whitespace is optional. These were all tested on [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

If you'd like the entire string altogether to be between 3 and 30 characters you can use lookaheads adding `(?=^.{3,30}$)` at the beginning of the RegExp and removing the other size limitations

All that said, in all honestly I'd probably just test the `String`'s `.length` property. It's more readable.

Comment: @zvzdhk I don't understand your question, would you like examples of how the {n,m} quantifier should be used?

Comment: Yes, [a-z]{3,30} matches 3 to 30 letters, but mine would match 3 to 30 sets of two letters maybe with a space in between them, rather than real letters. Or at least that's what playing around with [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) seems to indicate to me.

Comment: @zvzdhk Fair enough :) I just edited, CorayThan please see my edit.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work. If I got OP's issue correctly, `aaaaaa bbbbbbb` should pass too. But it does not.

Comment: @zvzdhk In that case all he needs to do is change `[a-zA-Z]` to `[a-zA-Z]+\s` . Thank you for helping me improve my answer by the way.

Comment: Same goes for your last solution. It works except that the white spaces don't count for a space! So if there are, say, 3 white spaces you can have the java equivalent of a 33 length string.

Comment: @CorayThan I did not understand you wanted whitespaces not to count, I'm editing my answer, it only involves dividing the number of repeats by 2 :)

Comment: Haha, that would totally work ... if not for the fact that the \s needs to be \s?. I don't want to require the space between characters. When you add the ? it means you can create a match with only 15 characters with your solution. Essentially this is to make people chose "realistic" names for their characters. So I'm fine with someone being "Bob of booger Square" but not "bo   b      x" (image extra spaces, SO removed them) because it would make it very difficult for other players to search for their name with extra spaces.

Comment: Honestly, for your own sake, if the length check applies to the entire string I'd just check the string's .length property. It's easier and faster.

Comment: Yes, that's probably true.

Comment: i want any characters or any thing but length must be 8. how to achieve?

Answer (score 9):

This is what you are looking for

```
^[a-zA-Z](\s?[a-zA-Z]){2,29}$
```

`^` is the start of string

`$` is the end of string

`(\s?[a-zA-Z]){2,29}` would match (\s?[a-zA-Z]) 2 to 29 times..

Comment: This is much closer. I actually do want \s? rather than \s* because I want a maximum of one space. The only problem is I wanted spaces to be included in the character count. I was just thinking it would be fun to incorporate in my regex the equivalent of "(myString.length() > 2 && myString.length() < 31)", so I don't need extra checks in java.

Comment: Also, what is the practical purpose of ^ and $? At least in java my matcher seems to work without those.

Comment: @CorayThan if you use the above regex without ^,$ with **find** method,it would match anywhere..so it would also match any input that has more than 30 characters..if you use **matches** method it would match the pattern exactly and so you don't need to use ^,$ if you use matches method..more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex)

Comment: @CorayThan i guess this has solved your problem..if so you can accept the ans or atleast upvote for my efforts..right!

Comment: I suspect the real answer to my issue is that it's impossible. Like I said, counting white space the string length can exceed 30 with your answer.

Comment: @CorayThan It's possible, it can be proven (formally) that the intersection of two regular languages is also regular. Formally, I can _prove_ that there _exists_ a RegExp that matches your case (being exactly 30 chars and containing letters followed by whitespaces). I just don't think that you should use it :) (probably answer is using (?=expr) to check length without consuming and then consume with the current solution.

Comment: Good point. For sure, it is possible. But not possible with a reasonable regex. :)

Comment: @CorayThan you can do it separately..y do you want to do it with regex alone..isn't that **overkill**

Answer (score 5):

Actually [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum)'s answer will lead to the complete solution to the OP's question. 
Using lookaheads it is possible to restrict the total number of characters AND restrict the match to a set combination of letters and (optional) single spaces.

The regex that solves the entire problem would become

```
(?=^.{3,30}$)^([A-Za-z][\s]?)+$
```

This will match `AAA`, `A A` and also fail to match `AA  A` since there are two consecutive spaces. 
I tested this at http://regexpal.com/ and it does the trick.

Comment: Thanks. That example of a lookahead in action was precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
[a-zA-Z ]{20}
```

[For allowed characters]{for limiting of the number of characters}