# regex setting max number of letters in first name and last name

Tags: php, regex

In a form I ask the user to insert his/her First name and Last name with only a space between them, and no space before and after them.

I found the following code: `^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$`

But I would wish to put restrictions **15 letters max in first**, and **20 letters max in last name**.

Comment: Asking basic usage of a regular expression pattern, I wonder about up-voters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set min and max characters in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288519/set-min-and-max-characters-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 6):

Use a [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,15} [a-zA-Z]{1,20}$
         ^^^^^          ^^^^^^
```

The `{1,15}` limiting quantifier tells the engine to match 1 to 15 characters matched with the subpattern that is located immediately to the left of it.

More from the docs:

> The syntax is *{min,max}*, where *min* is zero or a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and *max* is an integer equal to or greater than *min* indicating the maximum number of matches. If the comma is present but *max* is omitted, the maximum number of matches is infinite. So `{0,1}` is the same as `?`, `{0,}` is the same as `*`, and `{1,}` is the same as `+`. Omitting both the comma and max tells the engine to repeat the token exactly *min* times.

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor. Your answer is very helpful!