# Can't get groups to work

Tags: java, regex, match, regex-group

i'm new to regex with Java, and i'm trying to extract all "lesson#" from this text:

```
<a id="lesson1" href="lesson1.html">Lesson 1</a>
<a id="lesson2" href="lesson2.html">Lesson 2</a>
<a id="lesson3" href="lesson3.html">Lesson 3</a>
<a id="lesson4" href="lesson4.html">Lesson 4</a>
<a id="lesson5" href="lesson5.html">Lesson 5</a>
<a id="lesson6" href="lesson6.html">Lesson 6</a>
<a id="lesson7" href="lesson7.html">Lesson 7</a>
<a id="lesson8" href="lesson8.html">Lesson 8</a>
<a id="lesson9" href="lesson9.html">Lesson 9</a>
```

I'm using this code to extract that part from my string:

```
String s = ""
        + "<a id=\"lesson1\" href=\"lesson1.html\">Lesson 1</a>\n"
        + "<a id=\"lesson2\" href=\"lesson2.html\">Lesson 2</a>\n"
        + "<a id=\"lesson3\" href=\"lesson3.html\">Lesson 3</a>\n"
        + "<a id=\"lesson4\" href=\"lesson4.html\">Lesson 4</a>\n"
        + "<a id=\"lesson5\" href=\"lesson5.html\">Lesson 5</a>\n"
        + "<a id=\"lesson6\" href=\"lesson6.html\">Lesson 6</a>\n"
        + "<a id=\"lesson7\" href=\"lesson7.html\">Lesson 7</a>\n"
        + "<a id=\"lesson8\" href=\"lesson8.html\">Lesson 8</a>\n"
        + "<a id=\"lesson9\" href=\"lesson9.html\">Lesson 9</a>\n"
        + "";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("id=\"(lesson[0-9])");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);

System.out.println("Find: " + m.find())
System.out.println("Matches: " + m.matches());

if (m.matches()) {
   System.out.println("Group 0: " + m.group(0));
}
```

The output i get with this code is:

```
Find: true
Matches: false
```

and in javadocs i read that if m.matches returns false i can't access groups.

Why if m.find() returns true,  m.matches() returns false? I can't access groups with this code, so what am i missing?

Comment: Please don't use regex to process HTML, since whatever you use, it is very sensitive to changes in the source. If you do this as a one-off, or exercise, then it is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `matches` method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern. You should call `Matcher.find()` in a loop until it returns false. Each time you call `Matcher.find()`, you can access the group for the current found occurrence.

```
while (m.find()) {
   String someGroup = m.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to the first half of your question.

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

"The find method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern."

"The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern. "

The difference is that the `find` method looks for a match of the regex anywhere in your string, while the `matches` method will only return true if the entire input matches. 
In particular, your regex starts with `id =` while your string starts with `<a`, so you won't get a match.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
    String data = "" + "<a id=\"lesson1\" href=\"lesson1.html\">Lesson 1</a>\n"
            + "<a id=\"lesson2\" href=\"lesson2.html\">Lesson 2</a>\n"
            + "<a id=\"lesson3\" href=\"lesson3.html\">Lesson 3</a>\n"
            + "<a id=\"lesson4\" href=\"lesson4.html\">Lesson 4</a>\n"
            + "<a id=\"lesson5\" href=\"lesson5.html\">Lesson 5</a>\n"
            + "<a id=\"lesson6\" href=\"lesson6.html\">Lesson 6</a>\n"
            + "<a id=\"lesson7\" href=\"lesson7.html\">Lesson 7</a>\n"
            + "<a id=\"lesson8\" href=\"lesson8.html\">Lesson 8</a>\n"
            + "<a id=\"lesson9\" href=\"lesson9.html\">Lesson 9</a>\n" + "";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\>([Ll]esson\\s+\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do:

```
if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

- `group(1)` instead of `group(0)` because `group(0)` returns the whole match, whereas `group(1)` returns the group for the first parenthesis.
- You do either `m.find()` or `m.matches()`. The difference is that `m.matches()` needs to match the entire string (see [Difference between matches() and find() in Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex)). Your regex only matches a substring inside the string, so the `matches()` fails and the `find()` finds.