# Case-insensitive string matching in Java without anchors

Tags: java, pattern-matching

***NOTE**: This is **NOT** a question about case-insensitive matching. It is a question about `regex` anchors.*

I'm having a lot of trouble doing basic case insensitive matching in Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class match {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String prompt="das101.lo1>";
        String str="automate@DAS101.LO1>";

        Pattern ignore = Pattern.compile(prompt.toUpperCase(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher mIgn  = ignore.matcher(str);
        if(mIgn.matches())
            System.out.println(str+" Matches " + prompt.toUpperCase());
        else
            System.out.println(str+" Doesn't Match " + prompt.toUpperCase());

        char[] cStr = str.toCharArray();
        char[] cPrompt = prompt.toUpperCase().toCharArray();

        /* Verify that strings match */
        for(int i=cPrompt.length-1, j=cStr.length-1; i>=0 && j>=0 ; --i,--j) {
            if (cPrompt[i]==cStr[j])
                System.out.println("Same: "+ cPrompt[i]+":" + cStr[j]);
            else
                System.out.println("Different: "+ cPrompt[i]+":" + cStr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
samveen@javadev-tahr:/tmp$ javac match.java
samveen@javadev-tahr:/tmp$ java match
automate@DAS101.LO1> Doesn't Match DAS101.LO1>
Same: >:>
Same: 1:1
Same: O:O
Same: L:L
Same: .:.
Same: 1:1
Same: 0:0
Same: 1:1
Same: S:S
Same: A:A
Same: D:D
```

If I change `if(mIgn.matches())` to `if(mIgn.find())`, I get this simple string pattern match working:

```
samveen@javadev-tahr:/tmp$ javac match.java
samveen@javadev-tahr:/tmp$ java match
automate@DAS101.LO1> Matches DAS101.LO1>
Same: >:>
Same: 1:1
Same: O:O
Same: L:L
Same: .:.
Same: 1:1
Same: 0:0
Same: 1:1
Same: S:S
Same: A:A
Same: D:D
```

Where am I going wrong?

I referred to [Case-Insensitive Matching in Java RegEx](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/case_insensitive_matching_in_java) and [Methods of the Pattern Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String.matches` requires the entire string to match the pattern. As if the pattern has an implied "^...$".

```
Pattern ignore = Pattern.compile(".*" + Pattern.quote(prompt) + ".*",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

is for a *find* like match.

This could have been done with the original pattern as:

```
if (mIgn.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found at position " + mIgn.start());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Matches return true if the whole string matches the given pattern. For this it prefix ur matcher with '^' and suffix with '$' sign and hence it is not going to look for a substring.

find() return true in case of substring matches also.

Have a look - [Difference between matches() and find() in Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex)

Answer (score 1):

`matches()` only returns `true` if the whole input matches the pattern, not if part of the input matches the pattern.

The input `automate@DAS101.LO1>` does not match the complete pattern `das101.lo1>`.

That explains the different result you get when you use `find()` instead of `matches()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `?i` regex with `.matches` for case insensitive matching:

```
    // ?i = case insensitive match
    if (mIgn.matches("(?i:str)")) {
        ......
    } else {
        ......
    }
```

Comment: On reading the question in detail, you will see that the problem was not about the case insensitive matching as much as about matching the beginning and end of string anchors. However, thank you for pointing out that the question title is misleading, even if indirectly. I will correct the title.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Utility method for **case-insensitive matches**

```
 // utlity method for mathcesIgonerCase
 public static boolean mathcesIgonerCase(String string1, String sentence){
     return string1.matches("(?i:.*"+sentence+".*)");
 }
```