# Java regex for XLSX file extension

Tags: java, regex

I have the following file name:

`ABC 14-15 PCEE qwerty checklist - checked by XYZ IDFFCFYYL-01 BB.xlsx`

I am using the following regex to test whether the file has `XLSX` extension:

```
String filename = "ABC 14-15 PCEE qwerty checklist - checked by XYZ IDFFCFYYL-01 BB.xlsx";    
private static final String checkXLSXfile = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(xlsx))$)";
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(checkXLSXfile);
if (pattern.matcher(filename).matches()) {
    System.out.println("Heaven"); 
}
else { 
    System.out.println("HELL"); 
}
```

However, the pattern fails for this file name. Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: Please try to replace matches() with find(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the [String.endsWith(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method?

```
if(filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xlsx"))
{
 // Do something
}
else
{
  // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the test i did in jshell

jshell> Matcher xlsMatcher = xlsPattern.matcher("ABC 14-15 PCEE qwerty checklist - checked by XYZ IDFFCFYYL-01 BB.xlsx");

xlsMatcher ==> java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(?i).xlsx$ region=0,69 lastmatch=]

jshell> System.out.println( "find "+ xlsMatcher.find() );

find true