# Java regex match not working

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match string using java regex, but my match is failing. What may be the issue in code below?

```
String line = "Copy of 001";

boolean b = Pattern.matches("001", line);

System.out.println("value is : "+b);
```

Output value is

```
value is : false
```

Comment: You don't need `matches` here, use `contains`, unless you want to match a sequence of zeros that ends with 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between matches() and find() in Java Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex)

Answer (score 1):

`matches()` tests if the whole string matches the regex. It doesn't. Use [`Matcher.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) instead. Or simply use `String.contains()`, as you don't need a regex to match a literal sequence of characters.

Comment: Thank you got it,, i would have used "*.001"

Comment: No, that would be an invalid regex. `.*001` would work. But don't use regexes where simple contains() call work fine (and are simpler and more efficient).

Answer (score 1):

`matches` will match the whole string. Use a `Matcher` and the `find()` method instead:

```
boolean b = Pattern.compile("001").matcher(line).find();
```

Or make your pattern more flexible and allow it to have something prefixing the "001". For example:

```
".*001"
```

For something this simple, though, Pattern is an overkill and a simple `indexOf` will do the job much more efficiently:

```
boolean b = line.indexOf("001") > -1;
```