# Why does not work multiple selection?

Tags: java, regex

Why does not work multiple selection?

I need to get all numbers from a string.

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(([1-9]\\d*(\\.|\\,)\\d*)|0{1}(\\.|\\,)\\d*|(\\.|\\,)\\d+|([1-9]\\d*|0{1}))"); 
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);      
        boolean matches = matcher.matches();
        log.info("matches: {}", matches);

        if (matches) {

          log.info("matches value: {}", text);

        } else {
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String value = matcher.group();                    
                log.info("value: {}", value);                                                            
            }
     }
```

When **text** variable equals to **" 111 222"** it works (111,222),
but if I set **"111 222"** (without first white space) only get (222).

I checked on regex101.com (with g flag) and pattern works as expected.

Comment: I get 111 and 222, with or without space at begining, with your code !

Comment: Please, try to update code version

Comment: you quasi-give the solution

Comment: Don't know Java, but can't you use `pattern.matches` or something? Equivalent regex `(?:(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:[,.]\d*)?|\.\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

matches and find begin to eat your string.

2 solutions:

or throw your test with matches()

or reset after:

```
 matcher.reset();
```

And see that: [Difference between matches() and find() in Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex)

Comment: Thus, to get all numbers I need only call the method find(). Right?