# Regular expression implementation in code

Tags: android, regex

I have created *regular expression* for checking consecutive three repeated characters.It is working fine while testing on [Online regex tester](https://regex101.com) but same expression doesn't seem to work when I implemented it in code.
What's wrong with my implementation?

```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z\\d])\\1\\1");

   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if(matcher.matches()){
        return false;
    }
    else
    return true;
```

Comment: What is your input and what errors are you getting?

Comment: @ShaishavJogani If i pass a string with repeated characters like "aaaabcefg" it is not able to detect it and returns true always

Comment: `matches()` returns true if and only if whole input string is matched. Otherwise you should use `matcher.find()` or modify your regex like this: `".*?([a-z\\d])\\1\\1.*"` (Note there shouldn't be line-breaks in input or you need to set `s` modifier)

Comment: I think this answer summarizes it pretty well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex

Comment: @revo Can u post it as answer so tht i can accept it?