# Java regex does not match as expected

Tags: java, regex

I'm starting with regex in Java recently, and I cant wrap my head around this problem.

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Z]+");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher("GETs");
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Matched.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Did not match.");
        }
```

Result: Did not Match(Unexpected result) **Explain this**

I get the output "Did not match." This is strange to me, while reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html,
I'm using the X+, which matches "One, or more times".

I thought my code in words would go something like this:

"Check if there is one or more characters in the string "GETs" which does not belong in A to Z."

So I'm expecting the following result:

"Yes, there is one character that does not belong to A-Z in "GETs", the regex was a match."

However this is not the case, I'm confused to why this is.
I tried the following:

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher("GETs");
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Matched.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Did not match.");
        }
```

Result: Did not match. (Expected result)

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher("GET");
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Matched.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Did not match.");
        }
```

Result: Matched. (Expected result)

Please, explain why my first example did not work.

Comment: Yea, sorry wrote wrong.

Comment: Not sure about the down-votes.  I've tried to provide a suitable answer for you though... :)

Comment: It is a dupe of [Difference between matches() and find() in Java Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [`Matcher.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) returns `true` only if the **ENTIRE region**
> matches the pattern.
>
> For the output you are looking for, use [`Matcher.find`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) instead

---

### Explanation of each case:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Z]+");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("GETs");
  if (matcher.matches()) {
```

Fails because ***the ENTIRE region*** `'GETs'` isn't **lowercase**

---

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("GETs");
  if (matcher.matches()) {
```

This fails because ***the ENTIRE region*** `'GETs'` isn't **uppercase**

---

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("GET");
  if (matcher.matches()) {
```

The ENTIRE region `'GET'` is uppercase, the pattern matches.

Comment: Thats not true, it clearly sais matching one or more times?

Comment: That applies to `Matcher.matches`, NOT `Pattern.matches`

Comment: @Pineda actually, [Pattern#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) also matches the regex, against whole String.

Comment: I still dont understand, according to the website: 
"X+ X, one or more times".

Comment: @Shashwat: so it does :-)

Comment: @Lurr: `Matcher.find` is what you are looking for.  AGAIN: `Matcher.matches` matches against the ENTIRE target region...

Comment: I totally forgot, i should add .* before and .* after.. yes ur totally correct

Comment: No worries.  If you found this answer helpful I'd greatly appreciate an up-vote and an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You're very first regex asks to match any character that is not in an uppercase range of A-Z. The match is on the lowercase "s" in GETs.

Comment: Yea but why doesnt it match then?

Comment: Because you're attempting to match the whole word.

Comment: Yes, but why did the 2nd not match then? Its the same.

Comment: The 2nd pattern is asking if the whole word GETs only _has_ chracters in the upper case A-Z range

[^A-Z]+ : Anything _NOT_ in uppercase A-Z
[^A-Za-z]+ : Anything _NOT_ in A-Z or a-z

Answer (score 0):

if you want a regex to match either in UPPERCASE and lowercase, you can use this:
`String test = "yes";
String test2= "YEs";
test.matches("(?i).*\\byes\\b.*");
test2.matches("(?i).*\\byes\\b.*");`

will return true in the two cases