# Why Matcher doesn't find pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm agreed that regex is simple, but I really don't understand why it can't find and extract data. Also, I have very little experience with Java, may be it's the cause.

**Method 1**

```
String access_token = Utils.extractPattern(url, "access_token=([a-z0-9]+)&");
```

Url is like `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=abcedefasdasdasdsadasasasdads123123&expires_in=0&user_id=1111111111`

**Utils**

```
public static String extractPattern(String string, String pattern) {
    Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = searchPattern.matcher(string);
    Log.d("pattern found - ", matcher.matches() ? "yes" : "no");
    return matcher.group();
}
```

Why it fails with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far`?

Comment: You have to call [`find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) first

Comment: Call `matcher.group()` only when `matcher.matches()`.

Comment: Side note: you probably want `matcher.group(1)`.

Comment: `matcher.matches()` will not match a substring like the OP wants. Use `matcher.find()` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `find()` method of `Matcher` class to check whether the `Pattern` is found or not. [Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) the documentation:

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that
>   matches the pattern.
>
> This method starts at the beginning of this
>   matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of the method was
>   successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first
>   character not matched by the previous match.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
>   start, end, and group methods.

Below should work:

```
public static String extractPattern(String string, String pattern) {
    Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = searchPattern.matcher(string);
    if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("Pattern found");
        return matcher.group();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Match not found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Would like to test, but remote service seems to work unstable. _Btw, should read the docs, but there's a lot of them on Java!_

Comment: this helps a lot after hours searching, thanks