# Java WildCard replacement

Tags: java, regex, full-text-search, jtextfield

I have a text field where a user is required to input information.

```
JTextField data = new JTextField();
```

I have a requirment that if a user enters in *****. Then it should be treated as a regex wildcard for when I search for the data.

I am looping through a series of files and reading each line one by one.

```
for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files[i]));
            String text = null;

            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(text.contains(data) return text; // Line that requires wildcard check
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
```

How could I achieve this wildcard check? I require to make the '*' become any character once entered by user.

Comment: Take the user input, loop through and if there is a star you replace it with "." as dot is wildcard for regex, then use that newly generated string as a regex for your search argument. Consider using StringBuilder as a variable type as a holder for user input if you plan on editing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between matches() and find() in Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex)

Comment: You say “treated as a regex wildcard” but I assume you mean that the `*` by itself should be treated as a wildcard character, as in `dsc*.jpg`.  Is that correct?

Comment: @VGR that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the search string may contain other characters which would be significant in a regular expression, so it isn’t safe to just blindly convert `*` to `.*`.

You’ll want to use [Pattern.quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) on all parts of the search string except for the asterisks:

```
String[] parts = data.split("\\*");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    Stream.of(parts).map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.joining(".*")));

if (pattern.matcher(text).find()) {
    return text;
}
```

Breaking down the above statement:

- `data.split("\\*")` splits the string by a regular expression that literally matches the `*` character, into an array of substrings.  Examples:

  - `"ab*cd"` → `{ "ab", "cd" }`
  - `"1*2345*67"` → `{ "1", "2345", "67" }`
- `Stream.of(parts)` creates a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from the array of substrings.
- `map(Pattern:quote)` replaces each element in the Stream with its quoted equivalent, so any regex metacharacters (other than `*`) will be treated as ordinary characters.  Thus, `"1+1"` in the original user input would actually match those three characters in the searched files.
- `collect(Collectors.joining(".*"))` reassembles the elements in the stream into a single String, with `.*` between each quoted part.

On a side note, you can avoid writing a `finally` block by placing your BufferedReader in a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
String[] parts = data.split("\\*");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    Stream.of(parts).map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.joining(".*")));
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("");

for (File file : files) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String text;
        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (matcher.reset(text).find()) {
                return text;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Because BufferedReader implements [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), an implicit `finally` block will be created which essentially does what you were doing:  try to close the BufferedReader while [suppressing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-) any exception that might arise from the close attempt.