# How to fetch multiple matched pattern from a single string

Tags: android, regex, string, pattern-matching, regex-group

How can I get patterns using find() method and store the matched patterns in a arraylist

**Input string: 9547235617/7865421341**

I want to fetch both numbers and pass it in to an arrary list.

Current I am using  the below pattern compile method to find the patterns as follows

```
Pattern number = Pattern.compile("^[789]\\d{9}$");
        Matcher matcher = number.matcher(list_string);
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            arraylist.add("No number available");
        }

    elseif (matcher.find()) {
                    arraylist.add(matcher.group());
                }
Log.e("Arraylist value is","==>"+arraylist.tostring());
```

In this methods it always go the the first if condition and when a try to run the same string in other regex testing program on online examples it only matches the last number as pattern I don't have any idea what to do next hope some one can help

**output: Arraylist value is ==>No number available**

**Note: I need to fetch both numbers and add it to array list.Currently I have used splits for special characters and store those splits in to array list but i want a method regarding regex pattern matching.**

Comment: the regex will match every number start from 7 or 8 or 9 if my string was like this 7865421341/9547235617 then also it will face the same issue

Comment: @S.Jovan- Sir i tried it but  output is same as the above .

Comment: [Difference between matches() and find() in Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches()` will only return true if the full string is matched. `find()` will try to find the next occurrence within the substring that matches the regex.

**Regex**: [`(?<=^|\/)(?:\b[7-9]\d{9}\b)?`](https://regex101.com/r/MemNOz/2)

**Java code**:

```
String[] aStr = {"9547235617/7865421341", "6547235617/5865421341", "4547235617/9865421341"};

for(String str: aStr) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\/)(?:\\b[7-9]\\d{9}\\b)?").matcher(str);
    while(matcher.find()){
        if(matcher.group().equals("")) {
            System.out.print("No number available" + "\n");
        } else {
            System.out.print(matcher.group() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
9547235617
7865421341
No number available
No number available
No number available
9865421341
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/QtP8Nz)

Comment: thank you sir Its working perfectly and also for the above document for find() vs matches

Comment: @krishank Tripathi Updated regex and code for better accuracy.