# Find Date Anywhere In Timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp

Is there a way to find the date anywhere in a timestamp? For example,

2017-01-31 01:33:30 random text log message x

where the data is in the beginning of the string or:

01:33:30 2017-01-31 random text log message x

where the date is in the middle. How could you parse every string to get the date in java?

Comment: `/[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}/g`

Comment: @Chris Java, not javascript. Also, square brackets are not necessary here.

Comment: Right yeah, was just throwing in a point in the right direction. Hence comment not answer. Appreciate the feedback here, though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use regex as below to retrieve the date.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher("2017-01-31 01:33:30 random text log message x");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); //print out the date
}
```

Comment: FYI, you could just use group(0) for the whole regex, thus making the parens unnecessary.

Comment: Awesome, can anyone explain what find does?

Comment: Here is a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex

Answer (score 1):

## Regex is overkill

No need for tricky regex matching here. Just parse the date-time text as date-time objects.

## java.time

In your example, only two formats are used. So attempt to parse each using the modern *java.time* classes. They are similar, one is date-first, the other is time-of-day first.

```
DateTimeFormatter fDateTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter fTimeDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HH:mm:ss uuuu-MM-dd" ) ;
```

First, extract the first 19 characters from your string, to focus only on the date-time data.

Parse, trapping for the [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = null ;

try{
    if( Objects.isNull( ldt ) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , fDateTime ) ;
    }
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    // Swallow this exception in this case.
}

try{
    if( Objects.isNull( ldt ) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , fTimeDate ) ;
    }
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    // Swallow this exception in this case.
}

// If still null at this point, then neither format above matched the input.
if( Objects.isNull( ldt ) {
    // TODO: Deal with error condition, where we encountered data in unexpected format. 
}
```

If you want the date-only without the time-of-day, extract a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).