# Java String pattern with words and numbers

Tags: java

I have some problems with the pattern in Java. I followed all of the steps in Regex but these lines of code are not working!

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9]{1}");
        if (p.matcher(id).matches())
        this.id = id;
        else
        System.out.println("Wrong format!");
```

Whenever I type ABCD-0123, it is false and prints out wrong format

Comment: And it's correct. 0123: that's 4 digits. Not 1 as your pattern expects.

Comment: `-` has to be escaped like: … `}\-[` ...

Comment: Either your format is incorrect, specifically `{1}`, or you don't know about [difference between matches() and find() in Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4450045)

Comment: I have tried to replace `{1}` to `{4}` but it doesn't work either. I have been figuring it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the regex condition by [a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9]+

- [a-zA-Z]{4}: contains letters of the alphabet and must be exactly 4 letters.
- Followed by a "-"
- Then digits [0-9]+(if you want to set the size of the replace the +
  by {n} n is equal to the number of digits

Comment: Not a very descriptive answer, would you mind explaining your answer and what the regex does?

Comment: [a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9]+

[a-zA-Z]{4}: contains letters of the alphabet and must be exactly 4 letters.
Followed by a "-"
Then digits [0-9]+(if you want to set the size of the replace the + by {n} n is equal to the number of digits

Comment: I was more trying to encourage you to update your answer with more detail, it wasn't really meant to be for you to add a comment.

Answer (score 4):

`[0-9]{1}` means only one digit (in the end of you pattern), and you are invoking `matches`, which considers the whole input.

Either adjust the digits to `{4}` or whatever you need, or invoke `find` instead of `matches`.

The latter (`find`) will... find the pattern inside your given input, instead of matching against the whole input.

Useful for patterns describing part of the input.

Comment: It doesn't work for me even though I changed the code to `find` instead of `matches`

Comment: An invocation of `find` with pattern `[a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9]{1}` on `ABCD-0123` will return `true` (`group()` will return `ABCD-0`). At this point I can only suggest you debug your code and find out what the given `id` really looks like.