# Java pattern asPredicate vs. asMatchPredicate

Tags: java, pattern-matching

Trying to understand how / when to use `asPredicate` vs. `asMatchPredicate`. Looking at the following example which produces the same result, is there any difference between the two methods or is it just matter of taste which one to use?

```
List<String> list = List.of("Java", "Groovy", "Clojure", "JRuby", "JPython");

Predicate<String> p1 = Pattern.compile("^J.*$").asPredicate();
Predicate<String> p2 = Pattern.compile("^J.*$").asMatchPredicate();

List<String> result1 = list.stream().filter(p1).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> result2 = list.stream().filter(p2).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result1);
System.out.println(result2);

[Java, JRuby, JPython]
[Java, JRuby, JPython]
```

What ever regex I use (for example `^.*y$` to get all languages which end in `y`), they seem to produce the same result. The docs mention that `asPredicate` uses internally `matcher.find()` and `asMatchPredicate` uses `matcher.matches()`. So is there any difference except they call different methods? Or are there differences, for complicated regexes than mine, between `matcher.find()` and `matcher.matches()` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between matches() and find() in Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex)

Comment: `matches` tries to match the entire string, so in your case it doesn't make any difference because you have `^` and `$` around your pattern, so you're matching the whole string anyway.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca All right, thank you. I get it. I am dealing with a list of strings and need to match exactly. So for my current use case it doesn't to seem to have a difference, since  I am not interested to match for a substring. Thank you.