# c# check for integers in a textbox

Tags: c#, regex, string, textbox, int

I am trying to check if a textbox contains a number. The problem is that it always returns that it contains a non-numeric character.
I've tried several ways, but none of them seems to work.

One of the ways I've tried is:

```
if( Regex.IsMatch(tb.Text.Trim(), @"^[0-9]+$")) // tb.Text is the textbox
```

It does not matter what I enter in the textbox, it always returns that it contains a non-numeric character (I tried entering 1-9, 'a', 'b')

Comment: Is it only one character in the textbox

Comment: Yes, I tried it with just 1 character and with multiple characters

Comment: Why do you use such a complicated regex instead of "\d"? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180354/regex-check-if-string-contains-at-leat-one-digit

Comment: Do you want to parse the `TextBox` value or do you want to check if it contains numbers?

Comment: I want to check if the textbox contains any number, if it does not contain any number I want it to give an error. Therefore i tried this:

`if( Regex.IsMatch(tb.Text.Trim(), @"\d"))
{
Debug.WriteLine(tb.Text);
containsLetter = true;
break;
}`

If i enter 3 in the textbox, it returns the value 3 in the debug window.

Comment: @wesley221 I don't know what validation you're doing before calling this Regex, cause for me it worked. Did you check if your `TextBox` contains any value?

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira I know for sure that the textbox isnt empty, since the debug window shows me the value from the textbox (also I just added a tb.Text != isnull to the statement, this didn't affect the result). 
Before the RegEx I don't have any validation, so as far as I know that cant be the problem.

Comment: @wesley221 This `Regex` should work. Did you try `abc123` to see if it matches?

Comment: @wesley221 "test1test" would be giving an error or passing?

Comment: your regex fails because the way you put it you declare that it shall only be numbers as indicated by ^(start) and $(end). if you leave out that bit it should work

Answer (score 4):

You could just parse the string to a specific number type, i.e.

```
double result;
if (!double.TryParse(tb.Text, out result))
{
  //text is not a valid double;
  throw new Exception("not a valid number");
}
//else the value is within the result variable
```

From your regex it seems that you need only integer values, so you should use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`long.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

---

Quick and dirty test program:

```
void Main()
{
    TestParse("1");
    TestParse("a");
    TestParse("1234");
    TestParse("1a");
}

void TestParse(string text)
{
  int result;
  if (int.TryParse(text, out result))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(text + " is a number");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine(text + " is not a number");
  }
}
```

Results:

```
1 is a number 
a is not a number  
1234 is a number  
1a is not a number
```

Answer (score 2):

You could replace your `Regex` for this:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(tb.Text.Trim(), @"[0-9]"))
```

Or for this:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(tb.Text.Trim(), @"\d"))
```

Comment: Nice edit, was just about to ask you to read the comment above.

Comment: what is mean by \d can you explain me the expression, i am very new to regex

Comment: @Blackunknown Yes, you remembered me that `\d` exists too.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `\d` is to match with decimal characters

Comment: I knew about both of those, and they dont seem to work either

Comment: @wesley221 Actually they work here for me. My string contains `abc123` and it matches.

Comment: @wesley221 try this site: http://regexhero.net/tester/ put the regex and your text and check whether it contains numbers or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can use TryParse:

```
int value;

bool IsNumber = int.TryParse(tb.Text.Trim(), out value);

if(IsNumber)
{
    //its number
}
```

Comment: I just tried this way, it does not work. It still returns that it contains a non-numeric character

Comment: it should work if its not a number, what you enterd?

Comment: I entered '3' in the textbox, aswell 'a', both of them returned true

Comment: you enterd 3 and a simultaneously

Comment: First attempt it was a '3', next attempt was the 'a'.

Comment: you must be doing something, i tested on my system it worked.

Comment: Double-check the basics: That you're reading from the correct textbox, something else doesn't change its value etc. Put a breakpoint before that part and see the value of tb.Text.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string check = txtCheck.Text;
            string status = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < check.Length; i++)
            {
                if (IsNumber(check[i]))
                status+="The char at "+i+" is a number\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(status);
        }
        private bool IsNumber(char c)
        {
            return Char.IsNumber(c);
        }
```