# Using comparator for several characteristics in java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a list to be sorted but it cannot be done if values are represented as strings. Example:

```
to sort: OB123, OB1212, Maintenance, Daily check, OB123
desired result: Daily check, Maintenance, OB123, OB123, OB1212
if values are strings result is: Daily check, Maintenance, OB1212, OB123,OB123
```

Therefore I need to use comparator to first sort aircraft numbers such OB123 by their carrier(OB), than by their number (123) and sometimes suffix (""). And after that I would like to compare the whole name with all the rest values as "daily check" etc.
So far I can sort only flight Ids:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(FlightNumberDisplay toCompare) {

int result = _carrier.compareTo(toCompare.getCarrier());
if (result == 0) {
  result = _number.compareTo(toCompare.getNumber());
  if (result == 0) {
    result = _suffix.compareTo(toCompare.getSuffix());
  }
}

return result;
}
```

So since "Daily check" has also carrier+number+suffix representation it is sorted according to it. The question is how to sort them according to their names.

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you can use [Comparator chaining](http://www.java8examples.com/how-to-chain-comparators-in-java-8/) (look for "thenComparing").

Comment: nope, I don't use it

Comment: One option is to write a string comparator that takes the flight numbers into account: If two strings both begin with letters followed by digits and the letters are the same, convert the digits into integers and compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can make a comparison checking for numbers in the strings:

**`FlightComparator.java`**

```
public class FlightComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
        // both have numbers, compare them
        if (containsNumber(arg0) && containsNumber(arg0)) {
            Integer i1, i2; 
            try {
                i1 = getNumber(arg0);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                return 1;
            }
            
            try {
                i2 = getNumber(arg1);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                return -1;
            }
            
            return i1.compareTo(i2); 
        } else {
            // no numbers
            return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
        }
    }
    
    private boolean containsNumber(String string) {
        return string.matches(".*\\d+.*");
    }  
    
    private Integer getNumber(String string) throws NumberFormatException {
        return Integer.parseInt(string.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
    }
}
```

**TEST IT**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] ss = {"OB123", "OB1212", "Maintenance", "Daily check", "OB123"};
    Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(ss), new FlightComparator());
    list(ss);
}

private static void list(String[] ss) {
    for (String s : ss) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Daily check
Maintenance
OB123
OB123
OB1212
```

---

## DISCLAIMER

Now, while this data seems correct for what you ask, is not a real answer to your problem. Also if flight letters are different ie, OM1212, OR1212, this will **only compare the numbers**, so to complete solve your problem now, you can choose between

- use this `Comparator` and compare data as shown (not using attributes)
- **adapt this `Comparator<String>` to `Comparator<Flight>`** (best option)

---

**CREDITS**

- Method `getNumber` created from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4030936/3850595)
- Method `containsNumber` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30133861/3850595)

Comment: Nice. As you said in the disclaimer, making it a `Compartor<Flight>` is probably even better, but we don’t have enough information for providing that. I suppose you should still sort by carrier before sorting by number. In `&& containsNumber(arg0)` it should probably be `arg1`. I’m sure the OP can fix such details.

Comment: I don’t know whether its nitpicking or helpful (or both): Last time I flew, the carrier code was “4U”. It may be that you should take digits in carrier into account too. It may also be that your code also sorts those correctly, I would at least want to test.

Comment: Note that there is an inconsistency: if both `getNumber` invocations would throw a `NumberFormatException`, a `1` is returned, regardless of the order, which violates the comparator’s symmetry contract. But since these exceptions shouldn’t happen anyway, the fix is easy: don’t catch the `NumberFormatException` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the carrier information in another List, there you can parse it by Integer using `parseInt()` and then sort it.

Later you can merge both lists.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.