# Asserting a random number with Android Espresso automation

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I want to assert if a string exists using Espresso.

The String Contains a Fixed part and a random number eg: FR#133, were the 133 is a random number. How can I assert it?

- It can be any digit number
- If number is not present the test should fail

I tried the below code that performs a fixed string FR#133 check.

```
ViewInteraction textView = onView(
            allOf(withText("FR#133"),
                    childAtPosition(
                            allOf(withId(R.id.toolbar_farmdetail),
                                    childAtPosition(
                                            IsInstanceOf.<View>instanceOf(android.widget.LinearLayout.class),
                                            0)),
                            1),
                    isDisplayed()));
    textView.check(matches(withText("FR#133")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espresso + UIAutomator helps solving a lot of problems which Espresso alone wont.

My sample Function that Creates a UiObject and assert the text in it.

```
public static boolean testNumberIDExists(String startString, UiDevice mDevice)
{
    String text="";
    UiObject uio=  mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().textStartsWith(startString));
    try {
        text= uio.getText();
    } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return Character.isDigit(text.charAt(text.length()-1));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check for this `HamcrestMatchers` and `regexp` (Regular Expressions).

According to first one there are many String matchers like `startsWith(charSequence)`, `endsWith(charSequence)`, `contains(charSequence)` which works perfectly with `Espresso`.

Check: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html

Examples: http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/hamcrest-text-matchers-junit-testing/

Tutorial: http://qathread.blogspot.com/2014/01/discovering-espresso-for-android.html

As an example:   `textView.check(matches(withText(endsWith("133"))));`

but as you're using random numbers, the most interesting matcher would be `matchesPattern()`.

Use regular expressions to check if your string contains proper Fixed part with number at the end.

Here's an example how to deal with it: [Regex: Check if string contains at least one digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180354/regex-check-if-string-contains-at-least-one-digit)

As an example:

```
textView.check(matches(withText(matchesPattern("FR#133"))));
```

Try also to simplify code to:

textView.check(matchesPattern("FR#133"));

Hope it will help.